# how to transform Future[Option[(Person, Future[Vector[Order]])]] into Future[Option[(Person, Vector[Order])]]

Tags: scala, future

I currently have this:

```
def maybePerson(id: Int): Future[Option[Person]] = ???
def orders(personId : Int): Future[Vector[Order]] = ???

val maybePersonAndOrders: Future[Option[(Person, Future[Vector[Order]])]] =
  maybePerson(is = 10).map(_.map { person =>
    (person, orders(person.id))
  })
```

How can I transform it into (merge the two futurs into one):

```
val maybePersonAndOrders: Future[Option[(Person, Vector[Order])]] = ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider [`OptionT`](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/optiont.html) monad transformer

```
(for {
  person <- OptionT(maybePerson(42))
  orders <- OptionT.liftF(orders(person.id))
} yield {
  (person, orders)
}).value
```

Here is a working example

```
import cats.data.OptionT
import cats.implicits._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

object OptionTExample extends App {

  case class Person(id: Int, name: String)
  case class Order(personId: Int)

  def maybePerson(id: Int): Future[Option[Person]] = Future(Some(Person(42, "picard")))
  def orders(personId : Int): Future[Vector[Order]] = Future(Vector(Order(personId)))

  val maybePersonAndOrders: Future[Option[(Person, Vector[Order])]] = {
    (for {
      person <- OptionT(maybePerson(42))
      orders <- OptionT.liftF(orders(person.id))
    } yield {
      (person, orders)
    }).value
  }

  maybePersonAndOrders.map(println)
  Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```

which outputs

```
Some((Person(42,picard),Vector(Order(42))))
```

Comment: what if `maybePerson` returns slick `DBIOAction[Option[Person], NoStream, Effect]` instead of `Future[Option[Person]]`? Is it still possible to use `OptionT`?
I tried, but I get this compile error: `no type parameters for method apply: (value: F[Option[A]])cats.data.OptionT[F,A] in object OptionT exist so that it can be applied to arguments (slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api.DBIOAction[Option[io.iproduct.model.Page],slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api.NoStream,slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api.Effect])`